# Default sorting is not working

Tags: magento, sorting

Please refer this following url http://www.trendycollections.in/kids-wear/boys-wear.html

All sorting is working Fine. But I have different issue. In the above url if i chose `Price lowest` under the `sort by` option then i will move to http://www.trendycollections.in/women-collections/sarees/designer-sarees.html, That category page also having `Price lowest` sorting.

If i chose `price highest`,Next category page also sorting by `price highest`

I think, i need to reset sort by option. I have set default sorting under `system->config->catalog->front end->Product Listing Sort by` as `Best value`. I can’t find where am i doing wrong here. if anybody know, please help me guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sort order parameter is stored in session. 
You can switch it off by calling `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar::disableParamsMemorizing` method 
OR
by setting params_memorize_allowed in catalog session. `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->setParamsMemorizeAllowed(true)`

Comment: Thank you for your response @Rajiv Ranjan, Now it works fine. I have followed http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7363/default-sorting-is-not-working

Comment: Like I said there, It will cause other problems like changing the display mode (grid/list) and page size, that will be lost.